# WordPress Plugin PHP Not Calling Function

Tags: plugins, php, wp-admin

I've recently created a custom WordPress plugin to keep track of submissions, reviews etc things on my website.

I built all of this in a single main plugin file and before launch I'm looking to clean it up a little and split the code into separate files.
I've spent the last couple hours trying to figure this out myself and have had no joy.

main.php

```
include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'reviews.php';

reviewsPanel();
```

reviews.php

```
<?php

function reviewsPanel() {
    ?>
    echo "test";
    <?php
}

?>
```

Each file is in the plugin directory and the plugin_dir_path function does return the correct path.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is main.php and how is it used? Have you tried echoing in main.php directly, to see if the issue is just with reviews.php?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your complete code, it's a bit difficult to answer. Also it's a big vague when you say that it's not calling the function (are you getting any errors / warnings?) If you've got error reporting turned off, please turn it on.

Also, try this:

```
require_once('reviews.php');
reviewsPanel();
```

If the file is not included, "require" will throw a Fatal Error.

One other thing I see is that the *echo "test"* in the reviewPanel() function is outside the PHP tags. So that will not be executed as PHP code.